# implementation of std::condition_variable::wait_until

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I am reading the libstdc++ [implementation](http://code.woboq.org/llvm/include/c++/5.2.0/condition_variable.html#121) of `std::condition_variable::wait_until`, here is the source:

```
template<typename _Clock, typename _Duration>
  cv_status
  wait_until(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock,
     const chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Duration>& __atime)
  {
    // DR 887 - Sync unknown clock to known clock.
    const typename _Clock::time_point __c_entry = _Clock::now();
    const __clock_t::time_point __s_entry = __clock_t::now();
    const auto __delta = __atime - __c_entry;
    const auto __s_atime = __s_entry + __delta;

    return __wait_until_impl(__lock, __s_atime);
  }

template<typename _Clock, typename _Duration, typename _Predicate>
  bool
  wait_until(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock,
     const chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Duration>& __atime,
     _Predicate __p)
  {
    while (!__p())
      if (wait_until(__lock, __atime) == cv_status::timeout)
        return __p();
    return true;
  }
```

The second function call the first function in a loop.which will do clock sync operation.So if we call the second function,the sync operation may run many times.It is necessary to sync clock every time?I think the code can be improved by sync clock only once in the second function.Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and no.

Yes, this code could be optimized to not manipulate `time_point`s when it loops. However, I'm not sure that's really necessary.

Consider what makes the predicated [`wait_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) loop.

When [notified](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one), it checks the predicate to see if there is work to do.

1. If the predicate returns true, i.e. the condition protected by the condition variable is true, `wait_until` returns `true`.
2. If the timeout elapses, `wait_until` returns the value of the predicate, which will typically be `false` (otherwise we would have expected the `condition_variable` to have have been notified).

This leaves only one case where the loop actually loops: When the `condition_variable` is notified, but the predicate returns `false`.

This is known as a [spurious wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) and is hardly the typical case, so it is not really worth optimizing for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right. On the other hand the assumptions for using wait_until are usually that the event will happen only sparsely and the predicate returning true for all but a few instances of unwanted wake-ups. Thus the overhead of re-syncing the clocks should be minimal. Remember also that in this case the thread had to be woken up and paged in already, which is probably more expensive than querying a clock.

Comment: Can you please explain `Remember also that in this case the thread had to be woken up and paged in already, which is probably more expensive than querying a clock.`? I just can get the point.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin the thread had to be woken up to continue execution which is probably more expensive than the two clock calls - the point is it's not worth optimising for the general case. see also Sean's answer for more details on the usual assumptions for wait_until.

Comment: @BeyerStudios,Thanks for the explanation ,got it